# Grails - Spring security core and spring security ui plugin inconsistency- unable to login with a newly created user

Tags: grails, spring-security

I m using spring security core plugin 1.2.7.2 and spring security ui 0.2 versions for my application.

I couldn't log on using the credentials I created. The new user is in the database. I looked around I read about double encryption password issues going on between core and ui plugin. The issue is still persisting. I got it worked by commenting the beforeInsert/beforeUpdate methods in the User Domain class. I was wondering if the issue is fixed in the new version?

Is there a different workaround for this?  Please advice

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting for this in the latest release (0.2) - see the `grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.encodePassword` setting in the "Password Encryption" section in section 10 of the docs: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/